# How to add third party API's to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api, user

I would like to add a third party API, that performs a http request when the user adds their car reg and the resulting returned ID can be matched to products on our DB.

I'm looking for any documentation or tutorials that show the right way to perform this in Magento 2?

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? The answer is not simple but I created a plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate module for that. After that there is  controller where you need to create the function for getting the car registration detail and their respective id.
your link will be the
www.abc.com/index.php/custservices/index
Custservices is your module name and index is your function name